# ImageView coming out of parentLayout (RelativeLayout)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

I have an imageView inside a Framelayout and that FrameLayout is inside a RelativeLayout. I am loading the image in the imageView using Glide. But instead of the image getting inside the parent its coming outside of the parentLayout(RelativeLayout). Here is the screenshot of the layout.

[image]

As you can see the black frame is the parentlayout (RelativeLayout). Image is coming out of the layout. Here is the xml code of the layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/menuLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context="com.ignite.a01hw909350.kolamdemo.MenuActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:background="@drawable/menuframe">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressView"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialProgressBar.ProgressBar.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminate="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dailyKolam"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/activity"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/music"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Gallery" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/scanAndDraw"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Scan" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please tell me where is the problem.

Comment: try imageView width and height as match_parent

Comment: its coming all over the parentLayout(RelativeLayout) that black frame is getting hidden behind the image

Answer (score 1):

The bounds of your Relative Layout include the borders of the black frame. The image is within the bounds of the RelativeLayout. If you want it to be within the black frame, you should apply padding to all sides of the ImageView. How much padding will have to be determined by trial and error, and will be different for different mobile screen sizes.

Comment: will that be responsive for all different devices? is padding the best approach for this problem ?

Comment: To handle different devices, you'll have to override the layout xml for multiple screen sizes.